# Realtek sound drivers can't compile on up-to-date Linux

Tags: audio, realtek, proprietary-drivers

System: AMD64, Ryzen 5 
OS: Zorin 16 Core (based on Ubuntu)

In order to improve my sound quality, I decided to install sound drivers from [Realtek](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/pc-audio-codecs-high-definition-audio-codecs-software). However, the latest sound driver **only works** on kernel versions below 3.18. Is there a way around this, maybe by emulating an older kernel version to compile the drivers? I'm also good with alternatives for removing the tinny sound from my laptop speakers.

Note: I've used PulseEffects with presents, and they don't seem to help.

Comment: The probable reason is that the code has been implemented in later kernel versions. If you are having `tinny` sounds then it is likely that the speaker wattage is too low or not capable of playng low frequency sounds. You could always install Windows and update the question with comparative notes.

Comment: You should explain what your sound problems are, as it seems your real problem is "sound problems", not "driver problems". You tried to solve the first by trying different drivers, but that caused another problem. So maybe go back to the original problem first.

Comment: To clear things up: I'm using Windows, and dual-booting Linux. I've noticed that the sound quality is better in Windows, and can't seem to make it the same in Linux. I tried to install drivers, and couldn't. Is there a way to either install these drivers, or make my sound quality better?